# getopt_long not working as expected

Tags: linux, parsing, command-line, getopt-long

I have the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>     
#include <getopt.h>       

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    const struct option longopts[]={
        {"one", required_argument, 0, '1'},
        {"two", required_argument, 0, '2'},
        {"three", required_argument, 0, '3'},
        {"four", required_argument, 0, '4'},
        {"five", required_argument, 0, '5'},
        {0,0,0,0}
    };

    const char* shortopts="1:2:3:4:5:";
    int c;
    c = -1;
    for(;;){
        int optind = 0;
        c = getopt_long(argc, argv, shortopts, longopts, &optind);
        if(c<0)
            break;
        switch(c){
            case 0:
            case '1':
            case '2':
            case '3':
            case '4':
            case '5':
                fprintf(stdout, "----------------------------------------\n");
                fprintf(stdout, "c = %c\n", c);
                fprintf(stdout, "optindd = %d\n", optind);
                fprintf(stdout, "val = %c, \n", longopts[optind].val);
                fprintf(stdout, "name = %s\n", longopts[optind].name);
                fprintf(stdout, "optarg = %s\n", optarg);
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Input:

```
./a.out --one 1 -2 two --three 3 -4 four --five 5
```

Expected output:
I want to print members of the struct option (name and val) when its   corresponding shortopt/longopt is encountered.

The above code prints the following with some unexpected outputs :

```
----------------------------------------
c = 1
optindd = 0
val = 1, 
name = one
optarg = 1
---------------------------------------- 
c = 2
optindd = 0           // expected 1
val = 1,         // expected 2      
name = one        // expected two
optarg = two
----------------------------------------
c = 3
optindd = 2
val = 3, 
name = three
optarg = 3
---------------------------------------- 
c = 4
optindd = 0          // expected 3
val = 1,        // expected 4
name = one       // expected four
val = four
----------------------------------------
c = 5
optindd = 4
val = 5, 
name = five
val = 5
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `longindex` return argument to `getopt_long` is only set for long options, not for short options. There is no way for `getopt_long` to know which long option corresponds to a given short option (although the correspondence may seem obvious to you). If a short option is found, the `longindex` variable is unchanged, so you should initialize to a value you can recognized (like -1) rather than initializing it to 0.

By the way, `optind` is a global variable maintained by `getopt`, which you will need in order to process positional arguments once you have finished with the flags. It's unwise (though legal) to cover this variable with a local variable with the same name; it is both confusing for readers and awkward when you need the value.

None of that helps you identify the long option corresponding to a given short option. That is totally your responsibility, if you feel you need that information. You could, for example, search the longopts structure for a `val` corresponding to the short option found; you would then have to deal with the possibilities that a given short option occurs zero or more than one times in that structure.

As a simple example, instead of:

```
int optindex = 0;
c = getopt_long(argc, argv, shortopts, longopts, &optindex);
```

you could do something like:

```
int optindex = -1;
c = getopt_long(argc, argv, shortopts, longopts, &optindex);
if (optindex == -1) {
  for (optindex = 0; longopts[optindex].name, ++optindex) {
    if (longopts[optindex].val == c) break;
  }
  if (longopts[optindex].name == NULL) {
    // the short option was not found; do something
  }
}
```